# Swift warning: 'weak' should not be applied to a property declaration in a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, weak-references

Looks like [weak references will be disallowed in protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0186-remove-ownership-keyword-support-in-protocols.md). So what am I supposed to do if I wanna add a weak reference? Any better idea?

```
protocol PipelineElementDelegate: class {
    func someFunc()
}
protocol PipelineElement {
    weak var delegate: PipelineElementDelegate? { get set}
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply remove the `weak` keyword from the protocol and declare the property as weak in the conforming type instead:

```
class SomeClass: PipelineElement {
    weak var delegate: PipelineElementDelegate?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'objc' to the protocol definition and the concrete class type and you can use 'weak' inside the protocol. Also ensure the concrete class conforms to NSObject i.e.

```
@objc protocol Calculation : AnyObject
{
  weak var viewModelDelegate: CalculationsViewModel? { get set }
}

@objc final class CalculationsViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject
{
}
```